# NancyFX crashes when trying to add a non string object to Request.Session["Foo"]

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, session, nancy

Using NancyFX and ASP.Net, i'm trying to share a Model object between routes, with something like this:

```
Post["/"] = parameters =>
{
    var myModel = new ExampleModel
                    {
                        Prop = (string) Request.Form["someField"],
                    };
    try
    {
        Request.Session["myModel"] = myModel;
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        return e.Message;
    }
    return Response.AsRedirect("/something/");
};
```

This crashes despite being wrapped in a `try-catch` clause.
Storing a string instead of `ExampleModel` works.

Is this related to `HttpSession` vs `Session` issues (ASP compatibility etc)?  How can I share a non-string object between routes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What's the exception? Is your myModel marked as Serializable ?

Comment: My bad... wan't marked as Serializable. Still, it shouldn't have crashed - It wasn't returning the message from the Catch clause - It just crashed (i'm running it on a remote server so I can't see the reason). Maybe i'll try to reproduce it locally later. Thanks.

Comment: @seldary I don't think your catch would have caught it as it's the serialisation itself that would have errored, which isn't done until it needs to create the cookie.